# XML Duplicate entery

Tags: xml

I'm getting duplicate results from an XML file. I want to know duplicate entry for ex   the field as No should not have any duplicate entry?
what can be the answer to resolve this type of error
For example

```
<RA>
    <No>123</No>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
</RA>
<RA>
    <No>124</No>
    <Name>raj</Name>
</RA><RA>
    <No>124</No>
    <Name>Hello1</Name>
</RA><RA>
   <No>125</No>
   <Name>sit</Name>
</RA>
```

Output Should be

```
<RA>
    <No>123</No>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
</RA>
<RA>
   <No>124</No>
   <Name>raj</Name>
</RA><RA>
    <No>124</No>
    <Name>Hello1</Name>
</RA>
```

Comment: What tools/languages do you use to process the XML?

Comment: Moreover, 124 is still duplicate in your example. Why was 125 removed?